# purpose of enabling APIs for google apps

Tags: google-api

what is the purpose of enabling API in the Google developer console? Is it just for monitoring / fees / etc? If an app is using OAuth 2.0, you can tell from the token the identity of the app so you can just monitor that way. What is the purpose of this additional step?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, it is for monitoring traffic, enforcing quota, and handling billing. An application does not necessarily have to use an OAuth 2.0 token to access Google APIs though. There are cases where when accessing APIs that do not require user data, API keys can be used instead. It also would not make sense to simply have all APIs enabled, as it is more reasonable to only activate the ones you need.